# How can I target $(this) in anime.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, this, anime.js

I am trying to achieve a click animation on a `<a>` tag. There are multiple `<a>` tags and all of them have the same class.

How do I achieve this?

As an alternative, I had tried adding a class as temporary to the targeted element using `$(this).addClass('temp')`

I need to know if there is a better way to actually do it.

If I go with the above method, I won't be able to bring animations with delays.

Sample

```html
<script>
  $("a").click(function(){
    anime({
    targets:'a',
    opacity:[0,1],
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: the code snippet does not work. Are you using `jQuery`? What is `a`? If `a` is a variable, then it cannot be seen in your example; if `a` is for `anchor tag`, then your selector is incorrect (it should be `$("a")`). Please, update your question, so the your problem can be seen

Comment: The snippet it's just for display and won't run anything. Yes, the sample had an error, it is supposed to be an anchor tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass `e.currentTarget` to the `targets` property (which [accepts a DOM node](https://animejs.com/documentation/#domNode)), so that you will target the current `<a>` element that the event listener is bound to. Alternatively you can also pass in `this`: it's up to you.

See proof-of-concept below. I have tweaked the opacity to 0.25 so that you can actually see the element before clicking on it.

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  anime({
    targets: e.currentTarget,
    opacity: [0.25, 1],
  })
});
```

```css
a {
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
```

Or just do it natively in JS without needing jQuery:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    anime({
      targets: el,
      opacity: [0.25, 1],
    });
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
```